# Restore nested fragment data android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a android app structure as follows

```
Activity -> Fragment -> FragmentViewPager with 3 fragments

(Generic Activity)
(Generic Fragment for purpose of resuability)
(Generic Fragment hosts a view pager with 3 fragments, 
each of these fragments has some list view and random other stuff)
```

Currently, in `onViewChanged` (I used android annotation, so the code below runs in a method with @AfterView) of Acitivity, I do

```
Fragment genericFragment = FragmentBuilder().build();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(genericFragment);
```

to add the generic fragment.

In the `onViewChanged()` of GenericFragment, I set up my nested fragments and viewPagers.

```
Fragment f1 = FragmentBuilder().build();
Fragment f2 = FragmentBuilder().build();
Fragment f3 = FragmentBuilder().build();

viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentViewPager(getChildFragmentManager()) {
    // return f1, f2, f3 in getItem();
});
```

First problem I notice is that when the GenericActivity is killed (via don't keep activity), the next time it is loaded, it seems there was already a genericFragment there in the fragmentManager. (`FragmentManager.getFragments()` return a list.

**Question 1:** What is the proper way to restore a single fragment (generic fragment in this case)? I can find the old Fragment. But what can I do about it? Or do I just call ...`beginTransation().replace()` with a new GenericFragment? can the new GenericFragment still receive the old data?

**Question 2:** Since my nest fragments have lists and stuff, I would like to at keep track of what the user has loaded and which page the user was at. I understand how to call the viewPager to get these information, but what is the correct way to store/restore these data for these nested fragments?